# Returning the value of a different Variable if one or more equal undefined/empty/null

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

Im trying to return a value of a different variable in such case:

`If {{Click text}} of a clicked element is available return clicktext
If {{Clicktext}} is undefined return {{Click ID}}
If {{Clicktext}} and {{Click ID}} are undefined return {{Click Class}}`

I've tried this but it gives me errors all the time

```
    function () { 
if {{Click Text}} == undefined  { 
return {{Click ID}}; 
} 

if else ({{Click Text}} === undefined || {{Click ID}} == undefined ) {
return {{Click Classes}};
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
   function () { 
       if ({{Click Text}} == undefined)  { 
           return {{Click ID}}; 
       } else if ({{Click Text}} === undefined || {{Click ID}} == undefined ) {
             return {{Click Classes}};
       }
   }
```

The statement you are testing should be encapsulated in parentheses. This is not the case with the if-statement you have posted. Secondly if else is not a valid conditional statement.

Comment: Its the same code just looking better, and does not work :(

Comment: No, I did change the statement form "if else" to "else if". Can you post the error you get?

Comment: Error at line 9, character 4: Parse error. '(' expected

Comment: Try encapsulating the condition you want to test with parentheses. The condition in the if-statement is not encapsulated with parentheses. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Why do you mean by encapsulating?

Comment: Encapsulate means wrap. Your code looks like this: if {{Click Text}} == undefined.
If you see my answer I have wrapped the code after if with parentheses.

Comment: I dont know if I have explained it correctly. I want the function to look at the values of each of the variables, step by step -> if click text empty return click id -> if click id empty -> return click classes

Comment: Well, you example of an if-statement is not valid.